# How to add a new domain to an existing google managed SSL certificate using GCloud command

Tags: gcloud, gcloud-cli

Trying to add a new domain to a google managed ssl certificate using gcloud cli.

gcloud compute ssl-certificates create ssl-cert-1 --domains [www.site1.com](http://www.site1.com)

How to add `www.site2.com` to `ssl-cert-1`?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6):

The Cloud SDK interface for the `compute ssl-certificates` resources only has 4 [methods](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssl-certificates#COMMAND):

- `create`
- `delete`
- `describe`
- `list`

To be able to add a new domain to your SSL certificate you will need to delete the certificate and create a new one adding both domains with the `--domains` flag:

```
gcloud compute ssl-certificates create ssl-cert-1 --domains www.site1.com,www.site2.com
```